# SQL trace in Great Plains shows Invalid column name 'desSPRkmhBBCreh'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler, dynamics-gp

This error seems to just pop up now and again.  It is not restricted to a single table and even happens on tables it just created.  Anybody else see this weird behavior?

[Edit w/solution] It turns out that this query is used to determine if the table exists.  Apparently it is much quicker to query an invalid column than just check for a table.  Sql, go figure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like someone else has seen it:
http://microsoft-programming.hostweb.com/TopicMessages/microsoft.public.greatplains/1866812/1/Default.aspx

Unfortunately, I can't find the knowledge base article they refer to.  Victoria Yudin there says "Take a look at KB article 875229 - it addresses this exact question.  Basically, this is a dummy value entered to same time in getting information 
from SQL and the error is expected."